Variation Maurer-Cartan form under flow
I believe this question is very elementary but I can't find a proof.
Assume we have an immersion $f$ of a disk into a homogeneous space $G/H$. Let $F:U\rightarrow G$ be a frame field of $f$ and consider the Maurer-Cartan form $\omega=F^{-1}dF$. Now assume we change $f$ by flowing along a vector field of $G/H$ and obtain a new immersion $\tilde{f}$ and a new Maurer-Cartan form $\tilde{\omega}$. Is it true that $\omega$ and $\tilde{\omega}$ differ by a gauge transformation?

Isn't $\tilde\omega$ just the pullback of $\omega$ by the diffeomorphism on the base?

Yes, but what if the surface evolves along the flow of a vector field of the ambient manifold that has both tangential and normal component? Can I say that $\omega$ and $\tilde{\omega}$ are gauge equivalent?

Let $F_1$ denote $F$ restricted to $U$ and let $F_2$ denote $F \circ \Phi$ restricted to $U$, where $\Phi$ is the flow of the vector field at some time $t$. I am changing the notation a little.
We thus have that $F_i: U \to G$ for $i = 1, 2$. Write
$$F_2(x) = F_1(x) g(x).$$
This uniquely defines another smooth function $g: U \to G$. Differentiating, we get:
$$ dF_2 = dF_1 g + F_1 dg.$$
Multiplying by $F_2^{-1}$ from the left, we get
$$ F_2^{-1} dF_2 = F_2^{-1}F_1 F_1^{-1}df_1 g + F_2^{-1} F_1 dg = g^{-1}(F_1^{-1}dF_1)g + g^{-1}dg,$$
since $g = F_1^{-1} F_2$. Note that in the previous formulas, when I write for example $F_1^{-1}$, the "inverse" denotes the inverse in $G$ and not the inverse map. We thus see that $F_1^{-1}dF_1$ and $F_2^{-1}dF_2$ are gauge equivalent, via the gauge transformation $g$.
Actually, what we have proved is more general. Given a smooth manifold $M$ and two smooth maps $F_1$ and $F_2$ from $M$ to a Lie group $G$, if $\omega$ denotes the left-invariant Maurer-Cartan form on $G$, then $F_1^*(\omega)$ and $F_2^*(\omega)$ are gauge equivalent.
